# JSON decode string in PHP (array of arrays) Special characters

Tags: php, arrays, json, decoding, string-decoding

So I have this issue when converting a JSON string to a PHP array. The data is sent via HTTP POST so I'm aware there may be some decoding needed.

Could anyone lay an insight on how I would use json_decode() in PHP to convert this string to an array?
`"[[\"37\",\"text\",\"\\\"\\\"\"],[\"38\",\"text\",\"\\\"\\\"\"],[\"39\",\"text\",\"\\\"one word two words. Hello? \\\\\\\"escape\\\\\\\" lol\\\"\"]]"`

The input was:

```
[
    ["37", "text", ""],
    ["38", "text", ""],
    ["39", "text", userInputtedString]
]
```

Where `userInputtedString` is:
`one word two words. Hello? "escape" lol`

^ Or any other Unicode values

Comment: Is that _actually_ what you're getting in the request? If so, something in the bit that's doing the posting appears to have gone a bit screwy.

Comment: Or you have an addslashes somewhere, or potentially magic quotes turned on, or both. etc

Comment: @JonStirling Yeah, it's just coming from Javascript as an AJAX parameter. Just with the standard `JSON.stringify()` on the array in javascript. It's so strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use utf8_encode before json_decode

```
$str = "[[\"37\",\"text\",\"\\\"\\\"\"],[\"38\",\"text\",\"\\\"\\\"\"],[\"39\",\"text\",\"\\\"one word two words. Hello? \\\\\\\"escape\\\\\\\" lol\\\"\"]]";
$str = utf8_encode($str);
$str = json_decode($str,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: This kinda solved it, thank you. I had to perform the utf8 encode in Javascript before passing the input through a POST

Answer (score 1):

What seems to be the problem?

Simply use json_decode like you mentioned.

```
$ans = json_decode($_POST["name-of-var"]);
```

This should do it.

Comment: It just returns NULL. Sorry, I should have been more specific

Comment: Ah interesting, it looks like my POST input isn't sanitised. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use uft8_encode (to send to HTML) and uft8_decode (to receive) but not the right way